# Get TypeElement from Generic TypeParameterElement for Java Annotation Processor?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

Using Java Annotation Processors I have the following type:

```
@NameToken(value={"startPage"})
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<StartPagePresenter> {
}
```

and:

```
public interface Proxy<T> { }
```

I have the `TypeElement` of `Proxy`as:

```
TypeElement pProxyTypeElement = // ...
```

Now I want to get the TypeElement of the Type Parameter `<StartPagePresenter>`.

I tried:

```
List<? extends TypeParameterElement> proxyTypeParamElems = 
                                         proxyTypeElement.getTypeParameters();
TypeParameterElement firstParameter = proxyTypeParamElems.get(0);
```

When I print `firstParameter.getSimpleName()` I get `T` instead of `StartPagePresenter`.

**How do I get the real `TypeElement` StartPagePresenter from the TypeParameter?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access the generic paramters, you'll need the `TypeMirror` cast to a `DeclaredType`.  `DeclaredType` has a method `getTypeArguments()` which returns a list of `TypeMirror` which represent the concrete declared generic parameters:

Following your example:

```
    Set<? extends Element> proxyElements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(NameToken.class);

    for(Element element : proxyElements){
        TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement)element;
        DeclaredType declaredType = (DeclaredType)typeElement.getInterfaces().get(0); //assuming there is an interface

        for(TypeMirror genericParameter : declaredType.getTypeArguments()){
            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, genericParameter.toString());
        }
    }
```

Should print `StartPagePresenter`

I prefer using the various visitors supplied with the API to smooth out this casting.

Comment: nice one sir, but what about getting generic of field element? like `List<String> mList`?

Comment: @Hendra Anggrian Did you find a solution for generics?

Comment: You can get the generic parameters by calling `((TypeElement)element).getTypeParameters()` - See the OP's question for and example of this.